# Cisco Switch: Limit mgmt access to specific VLAN

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

I want to limit the access to the management console of my cisco switches. My idea was to only allow clients of a specific vlan to access it.

In my current physical setup I have three unstacked cisco sg500x that are connected via sfp+ and fibre and have a trunk containing all vlans on it.

Right now i can access the management regardless of vlan. I would like to configure the switches in a way that no matter what port I'm connected to. As long as the client is not in VLAN 150 there should be no way for to reach the management.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure acls.

VLANs are only one part of the solution.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/ios-firewall/23602-confaccesslists.html